# Twitter Bootstrap carousel not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Do I need to download more library to run Twitter Bootstrap carousel? I just downloaded Twitter Bootstrap from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html. I think there is a problem with my javascript libraries. I can see images, left and right buttons but when i click to right for example, nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">


<script>
  !function ($) {
    $(function(){
      // carousel demo
      $('#myCarousel').carousel()
    })
  }(window.jQuery)
</script>

<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }


</style>
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="assets/img/01.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/img/02.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/img/03.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->







<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

<script src="js/holder/holder.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you aren't initialising the carousel with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    //options here
    });
});

</script>
```

**EDIT**
Here's an example with your HTML
[Live example](http://www.bootply.com/66090#)


 [edit](http://www.bootply.com/66090)


If this still doesn't work for you, maybe there's an issue with your CSS or JS files. You could easily check this by replacing your local files with CDN versions, here is one source:
http://www.bootstrapcdn.com

Good luck!

**EDIT 2**

Your [pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/GPzgdmhn)  is missing a jQuery link. If you change your head to the following I think you will be good to go ;)

```
<head>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        //options here
        });
    });
 </script> 
</head>
```

Comment: still not working. Do you know a working example code for carousel?

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.bootply.com/66090 . Other than changing the image urls, the HTML is exactly what you posted above.

Comment: still not working. I think there is some settings file which bootply using. Because same code is not working for me. Do I need to download jquery? I don't have a jquery library or something like that

Comment: > Do I need to download jquery? ... yes, for sure. Check my edit above

Comment: can you post the url of your page?

Comment: I am working at localhost. Can you post an example carousel page? I dont want any other component just a html page with carousel and necessary files(with their directories).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the "http:" on the following lines (if your pages are on your computer)

```
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```